Am i using the -k option for the #compdef zsh autoload function correctly?
I created a completion file titled _test with the following contents:
#compdef -k menu-select ^f

_test() {

compadd -- "Test 1" "Test 2" "Test 3"

}

If i understand correctly according to the docks when i press control + f this should show the completions i specified in the _test function but it does not work
Can anybody point me in the write direction?
I've tried wrapping the key i want to bind with single and double quotes but that did not work
I'm ultimately trying to call a set of completions via a keybinding of my choosing but i want my completions to be formatted the way utility functions like _describe, _alternative, and _arguments formats them when they are passed completions
i tried creating a widget in my .zshrc file and just calling the completions after retrieving them from the cache file but when i try to complete the passed completions via a utility function such as _alternative they don't retain the same format as if they were called from a completion file like _test which is why im trying to use the #compdef -k method
I ordered the from "bash to zshell conquering the command line" book and hopefully the completion section in there can shed more light on why i cannot get this to work but until it comes in i was wondering if maybe somebody can point me in the right direction so i don't have to wait for the book to get here.
